# Is there a "with/to" implicit in the verb "failed"?

Tags: ellipsis

The *New York Times* published an article that's titled with the phrase/sentence:

["How Republicans Failed the Unvaccinated"](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/06/opinion/covid-vaccine-republicans.html)

I feel like there is a complement missing. And it should be like:

How Republicans Failed (with/to) the Unvaccinated.

Or am I missing some grammatical rule?

Answer (score 2):

No preposition is implied or necessary.  This is using *fail* as a transitive verb, like [definition 1 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fail):

> a : to disappoint the expectations or trust of 
> b : to miss performing an expected service or function

So the sentence means "the Republicans have disappointed the unvaccinated", or "the Republicans have not done what they should for the unvaccinated".

"The Republicans failed *with* the unvaccinated" changes the meaning; it means that the Republicans failed at something, but it was something that used the unvaccinated, or relied on the unvaccinated.

"The Republicans failed *to* the unvaccinated" doesn't make any sense.  We only use *failed to* as part of an infinitive verb, like "failed *to remember*."

Comment: can yuo expline: ""The Republicans failed with the unvaccinated" changes the meaning; it means that the Republicans failed at something, but it was something that used the unvaccinated, or relied on the unvaccinated." in a different way please? I had some dificult to understand it

Comment: _I failed with the first method I tried, but succeeded with the second_ (My first attempt to do something, using one method, didn't succeed.)

Comment: Or "When I tried to sell vacuum cleaners, I failed with the first people I talked to" (I did not succeed when talking to the first people).

Answer (score 1):

*Fail* can be intransitive, or transitive.  This is an example of the transitive use of *fail*.

Here's how *Merriam-Webster* defines this sense of *fail*:

> **fail**
> *transitive verb*
>
> 1a : to disappoint the expectations or trust of 
> // her friends *failed* her
>
> b : to miss performing an expected service or function for
> // his wit *failed* him

[*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fail)

We can see from context provided in that essay, exactly what is meant by Republicans *failing* the unvaccinated:

> But in the end, it’s Republicans themselves — officeholders, media personalities, Trump — who had the best opportunity to do outreach to their own vaccine-hesitant supporters, to cut the ads and hold the events and otherwise break down the more understandable and sincerely motivated forms of skepticism. And so it’s within conservatism that the failure of the past year was the clearest.

In short, Republican leaders were responsible for guiding their followers towards making healthier decisions.  They failed their followers by not doing so effectively.